# Showing a drop down on button click in Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the split button dropdown from twitter bootstrap in my chrome extension.

When I use it as a dropup, everything works fine. However, if I use it as a dropdown, the size of the popup increases when the menu is displayed.

Can this be avoided? I would like the dropdown menu to be displayed below the button but not increase the size of the popup.

I am trying to mimic the popup menu shown in the Evernote Chrome extension popup for selecting the article, selection or full page clip.

Comment: It might help if you posted an sscce http://sscce.org